# Compute the determinant of the following Hankel matrix involving factorials: a$_{ij}=(i+j-1)!$

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, determinant, factorial

Let A be an $n\times n$ square matrix with a$_{ij} = (i+j-1)!$. Compute $\text{det}(A)$.

I've tried to factorise from each column the elements of the first row and then performed some row operations to generate 0's to use Laplace expansion but with no success.

I'm thinking that there might be some kind of recurrence relation for the determinant in terms of lower-sized determinants with the same structure.

Comment: Did you compute the determinant for small cases? If so, is there a pattern?

Comment: @CalvinLin The numbers get very large very fast.

Comment: @K.defaoite Sure, since factorials are involved. Did you try factorizing it? $\quad$ If there is a pattern, then it suggests that it's possible to use various techniques to pull out the pattern (as opposed to having not much of a hope of recovering the answer).

Comment: If you have a candidate, you can try to prove it by induction: $n! \det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^n (i!)^2$

Comment: My answer is motivated by the comment above by math54321.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the given matrix by $A_n$. From $A_n$, divide row $i$ by $i!$ for all $i$. Also divide column $j$ by $(j-1)!$ for all $j$. We obtain matrix $B_n$ whose entry at $(i,j)$ is $ \frac{(i+j-1)!}{i!(j-1)!}={i+j-1\choose j-1}$.
$$\det(A_n)=\det(B_n)\left(\prod_{i=1}^ni!\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^n(j-1)!\right)$$

$$B_5=C_5=\pmatrix{
{1\choose 0},&{2\choose 1},&{3\choose 2},&{4\choose 3}\\
{2\choose 0},&{3\choose 1},&{4\choose 2},&{5\choose 3}\\
{3\choose 0},&{4\choose 1},&{5\choose 2},&{6\choose 3}\\
{4\choose 0},&{5\choose 1},&{6\choose 2},&{7\choose 3}\\
}$$
For integer $t$ between $1$ and $n$, let matrix $C_{t}$ be the $t\times t$ matrix whose entry at $(i,j)$ is $i+j-1+n-t\choose j-1$. In particular, $C_n=B_n$.

From $C_t$ where $t\ge2$, subtract each row from the row above it, starting at the bottom bow and ending at the second row. We obtain matrix $D_t$ whose entry at $(i,j)$, $i\ge2$ is $${i+j-1+n-t\choose j-1}-{i-1+j-1+n-t\choose j-1}={i-1+j-1+n-t\choose j-2}.$$
$$D_5=\pmatrix{
{1\choose 0},&{2\choose 1},&{3\choose 2},&{4\choose 3}\\
0,&{2\choose 0},&{3\choose 1},&{4\choose 2}\\
0,&{3\choose 0},&{4\choose 1},&{5\choose 2}\\
0,&{4\choose 0},&{5\choose 1},&{6\choose 2}\\
}$$
So for $D_t$,

- the first row of $D_t$ is the same as that of $C_t$, $(1, \cdots)$
- the first column of $D_t$ is $\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0}$.
- the bottom-right $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix is $C_{t-1}$.

Hence $\det(C_t)=\det(D_t)=\det(C_{t-1})$, for all $2\le t\le n$. That implies $\det(C_n)=\det(C_1)=1$. So $\det(B_n)=\det(C_n)=1$.

$$\det(A_n)=\left(\prod_{i=1}^ni!\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^n(j-1)!\right)=n!(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}j!)^2$$